# Haskell function for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I trust you're all doing well. I'm reaching out with a humble request. I've been working on a series of Haskell exercises I discovered online, and things have been progressing smoothly. However, I've hit a bit of a roadblock with my current assignment, which involves implementing a Tic-Tac-Toe function. The task requires me to create the following function:

Task: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OKb.png)

I was wondering if any of you might be available to offer some guidance or assistance on this matter?

I genuinely appreciate your time and support!

I have tried to create a separate function where I have created a playing field without the 'x' or 'o' filled with blank spaces.

Comment: [so] is not a free code writing service, you should make an honest attempt and when you hit any specific problem you can ask about that problem again. You can take the [tour] and read [ask] on how that question should be phrased for best results.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question you should ask yourself is : what data structure should I use to store the state of my Tic Tac Toe game ? Let's call this type `Board`, I will let you find out what this should be.

Once you've answered that question, you should implement small functions that do simple tasks for this datatype. For instance you could implement a function

```hs
circPlay :: (Int, Int) -> Board -> Board
```

that allows the circle player to play on a certain square. Then you'll probably realize that you should handle cases when the square is not on the board, etc. And that maybe you want as many players as you want, and you'll probably come up with more and more ideas to generalize the code you started to write.

For instance instead of `circPlay`, you'll probably realise that it's better to use

```hs
play :: Char -> (Int, Int) -> Board -> Board
```

so that there are as many players possible as there are characters. Following this step by step, you will eventually be able to implement Tic Tac Toe. One small step after the other !